# Unable to proceed with the game after a certain mission

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

i have completed 24.5% (The multi target assassination) after that under none of the characters it doesn't show any sign on how to proceed the game except the ? sign. Please suggest on how to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably waiting for a phone call on one of your characters. Go in-game and walk around each of them for 5-10 minutes. You might as well do the ? missions too.

Answer (score -2):

It's franklin. Play as him till Lester calls about his new house